# Extracción valor prioritario en función de rango

Tags: excel

Estoy teniendo algunos problemillas para hacer algo que creo que debería ser sencillo...  Pongo un ejemplo:

Tengo una tabla en una hoja, tal que así:

Columna A | Columna B

Roberto   | Medio

Roberto   | Alto

Roberto   | Bajo

Antonio   | Bajo

Antonio   | Medio

La idea es que en otra hoja, aparezca solamente:

Roberto | Alto

Antonio | Medio

Es decir, coger los valores de cada nombre con más valor. Si fueran números no tendría problema, pero al ser texto no sé cómo hacerlo.. ¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: si vas a tener solo esos valores(Alto, Medio, Bajo) podrias usar el filter para obtener los valores deseados por ese criterio

Comment: ejemplo: miModel.objects.all().filter(columnaB='Alto'),,,con eso tendrias solo los altos...y asi sucesivamente...

Comment: Bienvenido @OxidH a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y de paso ganes tu primera medalla, también es muy importante que leas [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad, favoreciendo tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Comment: Para ayudarte mejor, sugiero que proporciones cuales son las reglas para seleccionar los datos de la **Columna B** ya que se escoge **Alto** en el caso de **Roberto**, esto hace deducir que la regla de selección es por orden alfabético, pero al extrapolar dicha lógica con **Antonio** se esperaría que sea **Bajo**, pero lo posteado es **Medio**.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido a SO en español.

Lo que yo hago es contar si primero aparece `ALTO` asociado a ese nombre, porque sería mi valor máximo. Si aparece, pues pongo ese valor, y si no, cuento el siguiente en mi escala.

He representado los datos así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La fórmula que tengo en `B10` es así:

```
=SI(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$1:$A$5;A10;B1:B5;"ALTO")=1;"ALTO";SI(CONTAR.SI.CONJUNTO($A$1:$A$5;A10;B1:B5;"MEDIO")=1;"MEDIO";"BAJO"))
```

Y si cambio el nombre que tengo en `A10` al valor `ANTONIO`, mi fórmula devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que puedas adaptarlo a tus necesidades.